# WSO2 signing system service app

Tags: wso2, signing, wso2-iot

I want to setup all my devices as COPE. WSO2 EMM setup is complete and working fine. Only thing is left is to sign the system service application with the firmware key. I am using Google devices only (Android one, Motorola G2). From where I can find the key and password to sign the application. 
Is there any other alternative way to get the application signed?

As per documentation, "Sign the application via the device firmware signing key. If you don’t have access to the firmware signing key, you have to get the system application signed via your device vendor." 
But I am not able to find the device firmware signing key.

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of COPE enrollment types WSO2 IoT server supports, 
1. Device owner mode
2. Kioski mode
3. System application

The first 2 options can be used with any out of the box Android device. However system app is targetted towards original equipment manufacturers(OEM) who builds Android devices and maintain their own Android versions. This mean they maintain a version of Android OS image and does the installation to some customer device. If you are an OEM, you should have these keys with you. If you are not an OEM and still needs to use out of the box devices such as  Motorola or Samsung to install system app, you need to form a partnerships with those vendors to get the sign the system service app. Unless you need to perform operations such as reboot or firmware upgrade. You do not need systrm service app. In that case i would recommend you to go for option 1 or 2. What are the features that you are looking at? Also it is best to seek wso2 professinal services if thats an option for you https://wso2.com/contact/