# Issue with WSO2 IoT system service

Tags: wso2, iot

To make WSO2 IOT work with Android in COPE mode, I've installed the org.wso2.iot.system.service with agent.

When I try to enroll Android, it works but system application appears and I see nothing. And I can't enter a PIN code. I have to enter it manually in the app.

[image]

The device is enrolled and seems to sync but operations do not work. Ringing sometime loop, reboot does not work (still IN PROGRESS State), wipe does not work, and system service (see capture) appears on every sync.

I generated apk in debugCOPE mode, but adb logcat does not show anything

```
adb logcat org.wso2.iot.agent:V *:S
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you sign system service app? Do you have your own ROM?

As stated at
[WSO2 signing system service app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439736/wso2-signing-system-service-app/48460870)

*"system app is targetted towards original equipment manufacturers"*

According to the product documentation
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM330/Integrating+the+Android+System+Service+Application

you should have firmware signing key.